# Transfer specific data from one whole worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to transfer specific data from one worksheet to another?

What I want to do is to find all the data that has a specific string and transfer it to other worksheet. For example, I want to find data that has `AC` in it using the MID function, without any regards to its column and row, and transfer it to another worksheet.

So far, all I know is you need to have a specific range just like this code for it to work:

```
LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each MyCell In Range("E2:E" & LastRow)

        MyCell.Value = Mid(Range("A" & MyCell.Row), 6, 2)

    Next
```

But the thing is it only searches a certain column, what I want is to search all the data inside a worksheet. Is this possible?

1. The main idea is to find / search something in this worksheet that correspond to a certain criteria.
2. get the data.
3. transfer it to another worksheet.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter @pnuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might help you out. You may have to tweak it to your suitability.

```
Sub TransferAC()

    Dim C As Range
    For Each C In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B3").Cells
        If InStr(1, LCase(C.Value), "ac", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(C.Address).Value = C.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

To test this, create Sheet1 like so (and create an empty Sheet2):

```
  A           B
1 testing     racing
2 fencing     dashing
3 pacing      sleeping
```

When you run the procedure, Sheet2 will have

```
  A           B
1             racing
2                   
3 pacing
```

**EDIT**

If columns and rows are unknown but we know that they start from `A1`, simulate doing CTRL+DOWN-arrow-key to get the last non-empty cell in the same column and CTRL+RIGHT-arrow-key from `A1` to get the last non-empty cell to the right. That will be assumed as the non-empty range.

```
Sub TransferAC()

    Dim RangeString As String
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
    RangeString = Selection.Address

    Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
    RangeString = RangeString & ":" & Selection.Address

    Dim C As Range
    For Each C In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(RangeString).Cells
        If InStr(1, LCase(C.Value), "ac", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(C.Address).Value = C.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The other alternative is to give range from A1:XFD1048576 (all cells), but that may become impractical to use.

Comment: I think the code is still range bound? how can it work if the number of columns was not specified? like for example, if the worksheet has three columns, A,B and C.

Comment: @ayasocool The answer has been edited to use dynamic range with the assumption that data is contiguous in the cells below A1 and to the right of A1

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks bro. I've tweak it out a little bit and change the if statement to make use of mid function. Thanks!

Comment: I encountered a little problem with the code, what if column A has less row count from the other column, this makes the selection limited only to the row count of column A

Comment: If there are fewer contiguous rows than columns, the code should still work fine. If data is not contiguous, you'd have to keep on doing xlDown until you are at the bottom of the sheet. Remember the last place you found data